# i18next in front-end javascript

Tags: javascript, express, i18next

I have a problem with i18next in an express application.

I init i18next in my app.js file :

```
i18n.init({
saveMissing: true,
debug: true,
cookieName: 'lang'});
```

then i can call it in my jade template, for example :

```
h1= i18n.t('some.thing')
```

It's worked fine.

However, in my jade file, I call a front js file which display text in an HTML element. So I want to translate it but in the javascript file. What I want to do it's something as :

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = '<p>' + i18n.t('some.thing') + '</p>';
```

I try several configuration (init in the front js file, add i18n in res.render etc...) but none worked as i18n is not defined. How can I declare it in my front js file?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you trying to use i18next on the server and on the client?

Comment: quite that yes. I hoped i can declare it on server side and use it client side

Comment: The client side code is running in the browser so it doesn't have any knowledge of what has happened on the server, unless you are injecting some javascript into the page before you send it. I believe i18next can be used in the browser but you would have to initialize it in the browser too. Without seeing how your whole app works its hard to make a suggestion on how to do it though.